# An experiment to create a string out of character pointers but an error on the way

Tags: c, pointers

I typed the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");

    char *S ,g;

    g= 'p';

    S = &g;
    char *n;
    *(S+1)= 'V';
    printf("The output is %s ",S);

    return 0;
}
```

What I wanted to see is if I take the value of 'S' added with 1 and assign the character V to it then will it treat the pointer "S" as the name of a character string or not?
(Is it possible )?

What I am getting as an output is:
The output is (null)

Any suggestions and insights?

Comment: Agnivesh, read about the difference between the `char` datatype and strings in C (arrays of `char`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*(S+1)= 'V';
```

`S` is a `char*` that you set to the address of `g`, which holds enough memory for *1* `char`. You're accessing memory that your program has no right to access (*see bottom), so the bahavior is undefined. If you do not know the length of your `char*` string at compile time, then you need to allocate memory for your variable-length string using `malloc()` or a variant of it.

```
size_t N = 64; // if your string is 63 characters -- you need the 64th for the null terminator
char* str = malloc(N * sizeof(*str));
```

Alternately, use a static `char` array with a constant maximum size and go from there.

```
#define MAX_SIZE 64
...
char buff[MAX_SIZE];
```

- no right to access: You are not supposed to access an area of memory that you haven't reserved. `g` holds enough space for one char. `*(S+1)= 'V';` tries to place a `char` one byte beyond the region of memory that was reserved for one `char`, so the program might be accessing memory of anything else floating around; this could cause a crash.

Comment: What does "Program has no right to access" mean ?

Comment: @AgniveshSingh the memory adress `S+1` points to has not been allocated by your program -> you are writing to memory which you "have no right" to access, invoking *undefined behavior*

Comment: @AgniveshSingh See my added explanation above and UnholySheep's explanation.

Comment: @UnholySheep : Thanks a lot , got it !